# ConverFrom-JSON Error: Invalid JSON Primitive || PowerShell PoweBi Embeded Token Generator Code

Tags: json, powershell, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

ConverFrom-JSON : Invalid JSON Primitive error, primitive is not being recognized by PowerShell for some reason.

I need to generate PowerBi Embedded Tokens for my PowerBi reports. I can log in to my Microsoft account with out no problem and can invoke the report as well. At the end code supposed to return a embedded token to me, but I encounter with error :

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
>   At line:13 char:21
>   + $json = $response | ConvertFrom-Json
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

I have already tried the Out-String and Raw with Get-Content method, they did not work either.

CODE:

```
//Sign in with a user that has admin rights to App Workspace 

Login-PowerBI

//Regular Report

$url = "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=5515f33b-c114-41c9-a925-d1f85c323dab&groupId=e53e4fcd-16f8-46ef-8740-8e7167562ceb&autoAuth=true&ctid=c760270c-f3da-4cfa-9737-03808ef5579f/GenerateToken"


$body = "{ 'accessLevel': 'View' }"

$response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Body $body -Method Post

$response

$json = $response | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.token
```

It should return a huge paragraph of gibberish code, which will be my report's embedded token.

Comment: Try `$response | Select *` at a command line to see what you're getting back. Does it look like valid JSON?

Comment: It might be `$response.Content` you're looking for, not the whole $response object. 
Also, you're using $json.token before you've assigned $json a value.

Comment: It says Length ------ 28417. I don't know what that really means.

Comment: $respose.content did not do any changes sir.

Comment: It seems like the $response variable is not valid JSON. Sorry I don't have access to a Power BI login and can't test.

Answer (score 0):

$url is incorrect - need to call api.powerbi.com

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{GroupID}/reports/{ReportID}/GenerateToken
```

try

```
$url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/e53e4fcd-16f8-46ef-8740-8e7167562ceb/reports/5515f33b-c114-41c9-a925-d1f85c323dab/GenerateToken"
```